# How can we replace elements in a vector in R?

Tags: r

Lets say, I have a vector

```
animal <- c('cat','snake','cat','pigeon','snake')
```

And a dataframe called

```
map <- data.frame(find=c('cat','snake','pigeon'),replace=c('mammal','reptile','bird')
```

Now I want animal to be modified using the map by matching each element of animal to the replace column of map. So I am expecting:

```
animal <- c('mammal','reptile','mammal','bird','reptile')
```

How can I do this without using loops over each element of my first vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat `animal` as a factor and rename its levels.
For example, using the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
animal <- c('cat','snake','cat','pigeon','snake')
animal2 <- revalue(animal, c("cat" = "mammal", 
                             "snake" = "reptile", 
                             "pigeon" = "bird"))

> animal
[1] "cat"    "snake"  "cat"    "pigeon" "snake" 
> animal2
[1] "mammal"  "reptile" "mammal"  "bird"    "reptile"
```

---

**To make it automatic as required in the comment below**

```
repl <- as.character(map$replace)
names(repl) <- map$find
animal2 <- revalue(animal, repl)

> animal
[1] "cat"    "snake"  "cat"    "pigeon" "snake" 
> animal2
[1] "mammal"  "reptile" "mammal"  "bird"    "reptile"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How can we do this in an automated way? The example I provided is a simplified version of my case, where I have 40 different values. So I am looking for a way where I don't need to type 40 key value pairs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `match` function:

```
> animal <- as.character(map[match(animal, map$find), "replace"])
> animal
[1] "mammal"  "reptile" "mammal"  "bird"    "reptile"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose I use simple `recode` function. As input you need vector to be changed denoted as `x`, vector of values to be changes `from` and a vector of replacement values `to` (so `from[1]` is recoded to `to[1]`), you can specify `other` value and all the values that are not in `from` will be recoded to `other`. You can find the function pasted below.

```
recode <- function(x, from, to, other) {
  stopifnot(length(from) == length(to))

  new_x <- x
  k <- length(from)
  for (i in 1:k) new_x[x == from[i]] <- to[i]

  if (!missing(other) && length(other) > 1) {
    new_x[!(x %in% from)] <- other[1]
    warning("'other' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used")
  }

  new_x
}
```

using your own example the usage would be

```
recode(animal, map$find, map$replace)
```